# How can I vote in the Stack Overflow moderator election?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, election

I can't find the vote buttons anywhere.  Where are they? Am I unable to vote because of my low reputation?

Comment: Use the up/down arrows.

Comment: Why would you post a question for which you have to immediately apologize?

Comment: You should ask this on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @Matti I also apologized. Look at PS:

Comment: @Ahmet: Yes, and that prompted my comment.

Comment: You mean question/answer votes? You already did 11 up votes!

Comment: @Felix I know that voting bud. I meant election. Thanks for answer

Comment: @Ahmet Kemal: That is why I wanted to clarify it :) I assumed you mean the election.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the moderator election:

You [need 150 reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zgbE.png) to vote in the election, which you don't have. So you can't vote. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about voting for the moderators on SO. If that is the case, it requires a minimum reputation score of 200, given that you have only 80 points you can't do it for now.

Comment: thanks. I was asking election as you guessed.

Comment: It's actually only 150; it's in the bar on the right side of the election page

Comment: Right. But if you click on your reputation score, you will get the list of privileges that correspond to your reputation and if you roll over the "nominate moderators" link the message that appears says: "requires 200 reputation". They need to change it then!

Answer (score -1):

The two arrows on the left of the post are voting arrows up arrow for +vote and down arrow for -vote