# How to vote in moderator elections?

Tags: support, election

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) explains every detail of how elections work, except the most important one: how to cast a vote. The nominations period has started and it ends tomorrow, I would like to know how to vote for nominations, and where to find more info about it, underlying that this page isn't clear about it, so that you could change it by adding this info in future.

Comment: Once the nomination period ends, voting controls will appear (assuming you have enough rep, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77126/how-can-i-vote-in-the-stack-overflow-moderator-election)).

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361/187954

Comment: @TimMedora, thanks, was looking exactly for what you said (understood why no controls yet)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since there are 27 candidates, voting will occur in two phases: Primary and Election.

**Primary Voting**

In the primary phase, top 30 nominees ordered by reputation advance to preliminary community voting. As we only have 27 nominees as of now, they will all advance to this phase.Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the primary. This phase begins tomorrow.

There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down vote per candidate. The candidate vote counts are all public. Initial voting should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most electable.

All candidates are displayed in random order, unlike during the nomination phase, where they were displayed in a latest nomination on top manner.

After 4 days, the top 10 candidates based on primary vote score proceed onward to the election phase.

**Election Voting**

In the election phase, the top 10 candidates from the Primary phase advance to final community voting. Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the election. This phase begins five days from now

Each community member has 3 votes. You must cast your votes in order of preference, giving the `1st Choice` to the member you want to see elected most, and `3rd Choice` to the nominee you want to see elected third most. Last year having 3 moderator openings and three votes was purely coincidental. Even though there are four openings this year, you still get only three votes.

All candidates are displayed in random order.

The vote tallies are private until the election is complete.

After 4 days, the final voting results will be freely downloadable from this page forever, and we will calculate the winners using [OpenSTV](http://www.openstv.org/) with the [Meek STV method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method#Meek.27s_method).

Comment: What happens if you vote for 2nd and 3rd choice, but you don't select a candidate as the 1st choice?